# static/whereabouts IPAM cni plugins bin files are missing after installation in GKE on Prem

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking, cni, google-container-os, google-anthos

I am trying to install static/whereabouts (with multus) IPAM CNI plugin on GKE on Prem environment to create an additional interface and communicate with pods across the nodes in the same cluster.

Multus plugin is working well, but I am not seeing the bin file for static/whereabouts IPAM cni plugin on host directory (/opt/cni/bin) even after pointing the location in the daemonSet file.

**I am wondering whether static/whereabouts IPAM cni plugins are supported but GKE on Prem.**

Following is the changes I made in the whereabouts daemonSet file.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: whereabouts
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: whereabouts
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: whereabouts
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: whereabouts
        name: whereabouts
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: whereabouts
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: whereabouts
        image: ghcr.io/k8snetworkplumbingwg/whereabouts:latest-amd64
        env:
        **- name: CNI_BIN_DIR**

                                    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Added this
      **value: "/host/home/ubuntu/opt/cni/bin"**                <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Added this and point to the correct bin directory
    - name: WHEREABOUTS_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "100m"
        memory: "50Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "100m"
        memory: "50Mi"
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: cnibin
      **mountPath: /host/home/ubuntu/opt/cni/bin**      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  bin directory
    - name: cni-net-dir
      **mountPath: /host/etc/cni/net.d**                <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< bin directory
  volumes:
    - name: cnibin
      hostPath:
        **path: /host/home/ubuntu/opt/cni/bin**         <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< bin directory
    - name: cni-net-dir
      hostPath:
        path: /etc/cni/net.d
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install whereabouts IPAM cni plugin. Does not need to point to the cni bin directory (/opt/cni/bin) in daemonSet file.

However, I could not install static IPAM cni plugin yet. Dont know how to install from git repo.

Any help would appreciate.

Thanks.